# how to change color of <li> elements on hover using javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to change the color of `<li>` element on hover. Like in the following example code when I hover on apple or banana it shold shows the color brown to the corresponding `<li>` element to whole set of `<li>` element and when I hover on pear or fig `<li>` element It should show yellow color on corresponding `<li>` element.

HTML:

```
<div id="tree">
<ul>
    <li>apple</li>
    <li>banana</li>
    <li>mango
        <ul>
            <li>date</li>
            <li>pear</li>
            <li>fig</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
#tree > ul > li:hover {
   background:brown;
}
#tree > ul > li:hover > ul >li{
   background:white;
}
#tree > ul > li > ul > li:hover {
   background:yellow;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#tree > ul > li > ul > li").hover(
    function() {
        $("#tree > ul > li").css("background","white");
         $("#tree > ul > li > ul > li").css("background","yellow");
    },
    function() {
        $("#tree > ul > li > ul > li").css("background","white");
    });

$("#tree > ul > li").hover(
    function() {
        $("#tree > ul > li > ul > li").css("background","white");
        $("#tree > ul > li").css("background","brown");

    },
    function() {
         $("#tree > ul > li").css("background","white");
    });
```

});

https://jsfiddle.net/1v57nwg8/3/

Comment: ok, but what is wrong now?

Comment: when I hover on apple it changes the background of all elements of apple, banna,mango..I want to be changed the background of only element on which I am hovering.

Comment: May I ask why you are using jquery for this? Do you want different color on each element on the same level?

Comment: I would really discourage you from writing jQuery and CSS that use HTML elements as selectors (use classes instead).  It's very good practice to [Decouple Your HTML, CSS, and JavaScript](http://philipwalton.com/articles/decoupling-html-css-and-javascript/)

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty simplified and decoupled:

```css
.hover-brown:hover{
    background-color: brown;
}
.hover-yellow:hover{
    background-color: yellow;
}
.no-list-style{
    list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="tree">
    <ul>
        <li class="hover-brown">apple</li>
        <li class="hover-brown">banana</li>
        <li class="hover-brown">mango</li>
        <li class="no-list-style">
            <ul>
                <li class="hover-yellow">date</li>
                <li class="hover-yellow">pear</li>
                <li class="hover-yellow">fig</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if you will remove your jquery code it will do its trick because of css.

But if you still want to use via jQuery then,

Use $(this) as shown below:-

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#tree > ul > li > ul > li").hover(
    function() {
         $(this).css("background","yellow");
    }

$("#tree > ul > li").hover(
    function() {
        $(this).css("background","brown");  
    }
});
```

Demo:-

http://jsfiddle.net/Rj9bR/41/

Comment: when I initially hovering on fig then it is showing brown color on mango. Plz check your fiddle

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what do you want to achieve, but I think you don't need JS.

Look at the demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/mattydsw/1v57nwg8/4/

CSS below:

```
#tree > ul > li:hover span {
   background:brown;
}
#tree > ul > li > ul > li:hover {
   background:yellow;
}
```

I also added `span` elements in html markup.

Answer (score 0):

I had to edit your **HTML**, **CSS** as well as **jQuery**

- Added an extra `li` and gave it a `list-style: none; background-color: #fff;`
- Modified your selectors in jQuery to `this`

`this` will choose the current hovered element instead of choosing all of them

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#tree > ul > li > ul > li").hover(
  function() {
             $(this).css("background","yellow");
  },
  function() {
            $(this).css("background","white");
  });
    
    $("#tree > ul > li").hover(
  function() {
            $(this).css("background","brown");
  },
  function() {
             $(this).css("background","white");
  });
});
```

```css
#tree > ul > li:hover {
   background:brown;
}
#tree > ul > li:hover > ul >li{
   background:white;
}
#tree > ul > li > ul > li:hover {
   background:yellow;
}

#tree>ul>li:last-child {
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #fff;
}

#tree > ul > li > ul {
  background-color: white;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tree">
    <ul>
        <li>apple</li>
        <li>banana</li>
        <li>mango</li>
        <li>
            <ul>
                <li>date</li>
                <li>pear</li>
                <li>fig</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```